# How to show data like stats in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, charts

I have an app that compare population of courtiers (max 2), their compositions and this sort of data over a time.  But I still do not know how to show this data in my activity. All the data will be used from a JSON file.  What is the best option in Android to represent stats and data?

Comment: If you're looking to display stats via graphs then you can check out this library:
http://www.androidviews.net/2013/07/holographlibrary/

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should take a look here:

http://androidplot.com/

there is plenty of information about stats and dta graphics, also here is a complete example to begin:

http://androidplot.com/docs/quickstart/